# Find the best interval match result

Tags: c#, java, c++, algorithm

I have two sets of data in this form:

```
x   |  y  |  z        x1   |   y1   |  z1
ab1 |  1  |  2        ab1  |   1    |  2
ab1 |  2  |  3        ab1  |   1.8  |  2
ab2 |  2  |  3        ab1  |   1.8  |  2
```

The number of columns can change between 1 to 30. The number of rows of the two sets is likely to be different. 
The average amount of rows per set can change between few hundreds to few millions.
For each column a different matching rule will be applied, for example:

```
x: perfect match
y: +/- 0.1
z: +/- 0.5
```

Two rows are equivalent when all the criterias are satisfied.
My final goal is to find the rows in the first set with no match in second set.

The naive algorithm could be:

```
foreach a in SetA
{
    foreach b in SetB
    {
        if (a == b)
        {
            remove b from SetB
            process the next element in SetA
        }
    }
    log a is not in SetB
}
```

At this stage I am not very interested in the efficiency of the algorithm. I am sure I could do better and I could reduce the complexity.
I am more concern about the correctness of the result. Let's try with a very simple example.
Two sets of number:

```
A       B
1.6    1.55
1.5    1.45
4      3.2
```

And two elements are equal if:

```
b + 0.1 >= a >= b - 0.1
```

Now, if I run the naive algorithm I will find 2 matches.
However the result of the algorithm depends on the order of the two sets. For example:

```
A       B
1.5    1.55
1.6    1.45
4      3.2
```

The algorithm will find only one match.

I would like to find the maximum number of matching rows.

I reckon in the real world data one of the columns will store an id, so the number of possible multiple matches will be a much smaller subset of the original set.
I know I can try to face this problem with a post processing after the first scan. 
However, I don't want reinventing the wheel and I am wondering if my problem is equivalent to some famous, well known and already solved problem.

PS: I have tagged the question also as C++, C# and Java because I am going to use one of these languages to implement it.

Comment: Can `a` from `SetA` match more than one row from `SetB`?

Comment: "My final goal is to find the rows in the first set with no match in second set." -- obviously that is exactly equivalent to finding the rows in the first set that *do* match the second set. If you can find the set S containing rows in A that *do* match something in B then the rows that *do not* match are the set difference A / S. I would concentrate on efficiently solving the "is there a match" problem. Removing items from set B is a complete non-starter; you are removing items that might be a match to a different row in A!

Comment: Now here is an important question. You say that you are looking for rows in A that are *equivalent* to a row in B. **Is the relation actually an *equivalence relation*?** An *equivalence relation* is a relation x~y such that it is reflexive: x~x for all x. It is symmetric: if x~y then y~x. And it is transitive: if x~y and y~z then x~z. Equality is an equivalence relation; less-than on integers is not.  **Is your relation an equivalence relation or not?** There are techniques you can use to efficiently solve these sorts of problems with equivalence relations.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That's not clear to me. The relation "for real numbers A and B, A~B if A is within 0.1 of B" is not an equivalence relation. If you have x=1.0, y=1.05, z=1.14 then x~y and y~z but x does not twiddle z, so it is not transitive. If the actual relationship that is of interest is guaranteed to be an equivalence relationship then you can pre-process set B into equivalence classes, and then the size of the problem is potentially greatly reduced. But I suspect that technique will not work here.

Comment: @EricLippert: Ah, I messed up the transitive.  You're right.

Comment: yes, the relation is not transitive. I have used the word equivalence not in mathematical terms, but from the user point of view.

Comment: The naive algorithm is failing to find the exact solution, I have added it just to better explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be cast as a graph theory problem. Let X be a set that contains one node for each row in your first set. Let Y be another set which contains one node for each row in your second set.

The edges in the graph are defined by: for a given x in X and a given y in Y, there is an edge (x,y) if the row corresponding to x matches the row corresponding to y.

Once you have built this graph you can run the "maximum-bipartite-matching" algorithm on it and you will be done.

Comment: AFAIK, Corey's algorithm should be optimal for the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want the rows in the first set which don't match any row in the second set (within the error range). This cleaerly can be done with an O(n^2) complexity algorithm by parsing the elements in the first set and comparing them with the elements in the second set. 
An optimization could be this:

- sort both the sets - O(n*ln(n))
- eliminate from the start the elements too small or too big (within the error) from the first set - O(n)
- look in the second set for elements from the first set using a binary search (within the error) - O(n*lg(2)) and eliminate those not suitable
- comlexity O(n*ln(n))

Answer (score 0):

range tree? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree
i dont really know, just throwing ideas out there

Answer (score 0):

From the statement "My final goal is to find the rows in the first set with no match in second set." I understand that there can be multiple rows in first set that match the same row in the second set. In this case the solution is to remove the line "remove b from SetB" from your naive algorithm.

If however, you really need one to one matches between elements of the two sets then the answer with "maximum-bipartite-matching" provide by Corey Kosak applies.

Answer (score 0):

`Two rows are equivalent when all the criteria are satisfied. My final goal is to find the rows in the first set with no match in second set.`

```
foreach a in SetA
{
    foreach b in SetB
    {
        if (a == b) //why would you alter SetB at all
           go to next A
    }
    remove a from SetA  //log a is not in SetB
}
```

However, you are right, that this `is equivalent to some famous, well known and already solved problem`.  It's called "Set Difference".  It's... kind of a major part of set theory.  And since all those languages have sets, they also have that algorithm.  C++ even has a dedicated function for it.  Approximate Complexity of all of these is `O(2(A+B)-1)`.

C++ standard algorithm function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/

```
vector<row> Result(A.rows());
end = std::set_difference(A.begin(), A.end(), 
                          B.begin(), B.end(), 
                          Result.begin());
Result.resize(end-Result.begin());
```

or std::unordered_set can be made to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982739.aspx

```
std::unordered_set<row> Result(A.begin(), A.end());
for(auto i=B.begin(); i!=B.end(); ++i) {
    auto f = Result.find(*i);
    if (f != A.end())
        A.erase(f);
}
```

Java does as well: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

```
Set<row> Result = new Set<row>(A);
A.removeAll(B);
```

And C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875.aspx

```
HashSet<row> Result = new HashSet<row>(A);
A.ExceptWith(B);
```

Comment: thanks for you help, however std::set_difference is not good enough. The second example shows as ordering the two set can change the result. You can easily find an example where std::set_difference failed to find the maximum number of match (or the minimum number of no-match)

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi: No, I don't think so.  Your algorithm you posted was wrong, and I put the corrected in the top of my answer.  The corrected version is the same concept as the rest of these, and does not depend on the ordering of the elements in A or B.

Answer (score 0):

Given your constraints, I dont see a way to do it in less than O(n^2). I'd probably modify your naive algorithm to include either a bool or a count field for each row in table A and then mark it if it matches a row in table B. 
Then post process it with std::partition based on the indicator to group all the unique and non unique rows together. If you go with a count, you could get the rows that were "least unique". The bool would be somewhat more efficient since you could break out of the loop over B at the first match.